# Prove $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\cap\mathbb Q(\zeta_3\sqrt[3]2)=\mathbb Q$.

Tags: field-theory

I have to show that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\cap\mathbb Q(\zeta_3\sqrt[3]2)=\mathbb Q$ where $\zeta_3=e^{2i\pi/3}$. Is my argument correct ?

Let $x\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\cap\mathbb Q(\zeta_3\sqrt[3]2)$. Then there is $a,b,c,\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in\mathbb Q$ s.t. $$x=a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4=\alpha+\beta\zeta_3\sqrt[3]2+\gamma \zeta_3+\sqrt[3]4\iff a-\alpha+(b-\beta\zeta_3)\sqrt[3]2+(c-\gamma \zeta_3)\sqrt[3]4=0$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}a=\alpha\\ b=\beta\zeta_3\\ c=\gamma \zeta_3\end{cases}$$
and since $b,c\in\mathbb Q$ and $\beta\zeta_3,\gamma \zeta_3\notin\mathbb Q$, the only possibility is $b=c=\beta=\gamma =0$ and thus $x\in\mathbb Q$.

Is it correct ?

Comment: This proof is not precise. It is true that $1, \sqrt[3]{2},  \sqrt[3]{4}$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$, but for what reason?

Comment: ?? They are not in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)$, did you mean $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3 \sqrt[3]2)$ ?

Comment: No: I meant exactly $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$. Why do you conclude that $a- \alpha = b- \beta \zeta_3 = c - \gamma \zeta_3 = 0 $ (it deals with linear independence)?

Answer (score 5):

There exists a much easier way to conclude this fact. Note that
$$[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) : \Bbb{Q}] = 3$$
implies that there exist only two subfields of $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$: these are $K$ and $\Bbb{Q}$.

Now, $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \cap \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{2})$ is a subfield of $K$, but it cannot be $K$ otherwise you would have that $\zeta_3 \in K$, contradicting $K \subset \mathbb{R}$. Hence necessarily 
$$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \cap \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{2}) = \Bbb{Q}.$$